# unable to deploy my native react app in google play store

Tags: react-native, google-play-console

I am deploying a release of my native react application in google play console in production version, after review of my release by google play I have warning messages on: the size of my release which must be optimized with the format android app bundle, the API level that is currently targeting the API level 26 that should target the level of API28 and the version of the release that is currently 32-bit that must be 64bits. these warnings prevent me from launching the deployment in production version

I build my application by following the documentation of expo:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/release-channels/

I have research on developer sites (https://dev.to https://blog.mapado.com ...) but I had no solution to my problems

I expect that:
- the version of my release is 64 bits
- the API level of my release targets the API level 28
- my release is optimized

Comment: Have you checked the libraries you are using? One may be 32-bit

Comment: yes I checked all the libraries were checked. I installed them with the command npm install "libraries"

Comment: is there an observation I have to make?

Comment: If you have android studio, you can analyse the APK to see if there are any x86 libraries. You may include a library which is still x86 (32bit). If you have you'll need to get a 64bit version. Have a read: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: This warning is not blocking, I suspect there is something else going on. Go back to the Store listing, ensure you have answered all questions correctly. Same for the Disitrbution.